# How can I search though all deletions in a commit?

Tags: git, git-diff

I have a commit with many files. I would like to search through all deletions for a string (or regex) and be presented with a list of files that contain a match (ideally with the relevant excerpt of the deletion).

With `git log -p -S 'string'` I can scroll and search through all changes, but I don't know how to limit the output to a certain commit and I cannot filter for deletions in advance (I could start my regex with `^-` but that's messy).

Answer (score 3):

> With `git log -p -S 'string'` I can scroll and search through all changes, but I don't know how to limit the output to a certain commit ...

This part is easy enough: `git log`'s main function is to walk (backwards, as Git always does) through commits, one by one, starting from some particular commit.  The default is to start from the `HEAD` commit, if you don't specify which commit to start from, and to keep going forever.  But if you do specify one particular commit, it will start from there—**and**, using `-n`, you can tell it **how many** commits to walk through, so if you set this to `1`, it will "walk backwards" zero more times after walking through the one commit you specify:

```
git log -n 1 -p -S 'string' <hash-id>
```

for instance.

You can also use `--no-walk` to the same effect.  This is more useful if you want to examine two or three specific commits:

```
git log --no-walk -p -S 'string' <hash1> <hash2> <hash3>
```

for instance.

> and I cannot filter for deletions in advance (I could start my regex with ^- but that's messy).

Here, `git log` is not really much help.  You can, however, redirect the output of `git log` to a file, then open the file with any suitable command that lets you find the deletions easily (`grep`, your editor, whatever).

Note that `^-.*<string>` does not mean *look for changes that are deletions* but rather *look for changed text that starts with `-`*.  Unless you're looking at patch files themselves, so that the text *in the file* starts with `-`, this won't help.  The `-` generated by `git log` as part of the patch shown is not included in the regex search, even with `--pickaxe-regex`.

You might instead consider using `git blame` with `--reverse`.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have the hash of a target commit, you can use :

```
# to get the list of matches in that commit :
git grep -e 'string' hash

# to get the list of matches in that commit's parent :
git grep -e 'string' hash^
```

`git grep` also has a `-c` option to print a *count* of matches per file, instead of the full lines.

You can use that as an input for a script :

- if you mean "search through all files where the number of occurences go down" : compare file by file `git grep -c ...`, and inspect the files for which the number goes down
- if you mean "keep commits where the global number of occurences goes down" : sum the individual counts and compare
- etc ...